# access a member for an array

Tags: php, arrays, magento

The function where I fill the array:

```
protected function _getSimpleProductFromQuoteItem($QuoteItem)
    {
        $simpleProduct = array();
        $simpleProduct['size'] = (string)$QuoteItem->Size;
        $simpleProduct['shipping_attribute'] = $QuoteItem->Type;

        return $simpleProduct;
    }
```

where I am doing `$QuoteItem->Type` for example -  I get the value of an XML node, but that is working, I am saying it just for clarification.

So, where I am using this function:

```
protected function _setSimpleProductsItemsShippingAttributes($simpleProducts)
    {
        Mage::log('I reached the "foreach" ');
        foreach($simpleProducts[$simpleProduct['shipping_attribute']] as $item)
        {
            Mage::log('ASD: '.$item);
```

But I am getting `ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: simpleProduct` and `ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index:` and `ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` for the line of the *foreach*.

I tried also `$simpleProducts->$simpleProduct['...` but then I get error that I am trying to a access a non-object.

So I am trying to access this value, that is contained in `simpleProduct['shipping_attribute']` but I seem not to succeed. Ideas?

**UPDATE**
Where I get the filled $simpleProducts array and pass it to my function is:

```
$simpleProducts = $this->_getSimpleProductsAsImportArray($Product, $simpleProductDefault);
        //------
        $this->_setSimpleProductsItemsShippingAttributes($simpleProducts);
        die();
        //------
```

Whereas `_getSimpleProductsAsImportArray(atr1, atr2)` is the one that calls the function that fills in the array. I know it's twisted, but that's how the project is and how I got it. Anyway, everything until my function is working properly, so don't stumble upon that.

Comment: Is the value of $simpleProduct['shipping_attribute'] empty when you echo/log it?

Comment: @Ynhockey - no, it is not empty. It has the values that it is supposed to. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it like this:

```
foreach($simpleProducts as $simpleProduct) {
    $simpleProduct['shipping_attribute'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That also helped me improve my understanding about `foreach` loop in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
foreach($simpleProducts as $key->$value) {
    $key[$value];
}
```